# How to use jQuery selectors on Google's online calculator to find total amount of all calculator buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HW tasks to write a jQuery code on google's online calculator to do the following:
1. Total amount of all calculators buttons
2. Amount of numbers buttons (0-9)

I've done the second one and it won't work as needed it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

and can not do the first one at all..

```
var elements = $(".XRsWPe AOvabd");

totalAmount = 0

for (var x = 0, len = (elements.length)-1; x < len; x++) {
   totalAmount += parseInt(elements[x].textContent)
} console.log(totalAmount)
```

Comment: Here's a hint: `".XRsWPe AOvabd"` means an `<AOvabd>` element inside an element whose class is `XRsWPe`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fixed code :

```
var elements = $(".A2W7l .AOvabd");

totalAmount = 0

for (var x = 0, len = (elements.length)-1; x < len; x++) {
   totalAmount += parseInt(elements[x].textContent)
} console.log(totalAmount)
```

Output:

```
45
```

Comment: I am getting an answer 0 and that this row console.log(totalAmount) is undefined

Comment: That's because you didn't include jQuery before executing your script. You can check it as follows: type the command "jQuery". I think you are going to get this error: "jQuery is not defined", right? Just include jQuery in your script and you're all set